# Magento 2.1.7 How to Create a multi-language store

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7, language, multiple

How can i get to Create a multi-language store ?

As store view changes entire website language should change

Comment: follow this instruction 
https://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-administration/create-multi-language-store-magento-2-part-2/

Comment: Yeah thanks but i have followed it all, language are not change do i need to install any supporting extension for language change in localhost i am doing– k185

Comment: is translation taking effect in your site? I mean at least some parts are translated? if yes you can flush static file cache in admin->cache management.

Comment: How to add a Magento 2 Language pack?

Comment: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/add-magento-2-language-pack.html

Comment: check it out from here

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/extensions/content-customizations/translations-localization.html?_ga=2.33180350.1401828994.1510142761-2057627410.1503488976#q=Language%20Pack&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&hFR%5Bcategories.level0%5D%5B0%5D=Extensions%20%2F%2F%2F%20Content%20%26%20Customizations%20%2F%2F%2F%20Translations%20%26%20Localization&nR%5Bvisibility_catalog%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to set up Magento 2 multi-language version?**

---

1. **create a new website**: the way allows for creating a separate website
   with a unique name. Besides, you’ll manage to create and assign
   multiple stores, store views to it;
2. **create a new store**: the choice is justified if you want to make not
   only a localized version, but a store with sufficient differences.
   For this, you’ll need to create a website, add a store and store
   view;
3. **create a new store view**: the way is the easiest one, as you can
   simply add a localized version to the current store.

   ---

**1. Create a new website**

navigate to

> Stores > All Stores

[image]

Click the Create Website button

[image]

Fill in the website information, specify the Sort Order if needed and click Save Web Site:
[image]

Once it’s saved, you can see the website on the Stores grid:
[image]

**Create a new store**
If logged in, navigate to Stores>All Stores and click the Create Store button:
[image]
Fill in the Store information and save the settings:
[image]

Web Site: choose the website to which you add the new store;
Name: decide on the name;
Root Category: select a needed category from the drop-down menu.

If this handled right, the new store will be displayed on the Stores grid:
[image]
You can change all the previous store settings after saving, except Web Site.

Create a new store view
Once logged in, go to Stores>All Stores and click the Create Store View button:
[image]
Fill in the Store View information and save the settings:
[image]
Store: choose a store for which you create the view;
Name: fill in the name for the store view;
Code: insert the code;
Status: decide to enable or disable the store view;
Sort Order: indicate the order for store view display on the grid if needed.

The new store view will be displayed on the Stores grid:
[image]
All the configurations you set before can be changed, except Status.

If you need to localize the new store view, go to Stores>Configuration>Locale Options:

[image]

Choose the store view you need to localize, set all the Locale Options and save the configurations.
Now you have created a localized version of your main store. Thereafter, you need to install [Magento 2 language pack](https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/add-magento-2-language-pack.html). It performs full translations for Community and Enterprise editions (like files for standard phrases, email templates, etc.).